# Function Decorators in Python

Tags: python, function, return, python-decorators

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to wrap my head around function decorators in python. And I cannot figure out how functions return functions.

I mean in what order does interpreter interprets this function:

```
def decorator(another_func):
    def wrapper():
        print('before actual function')
        return another_func()
    print('pos')
    return wrapper
```

And what is the difference between these 2 statements:-

```
return wrapper
```

AND

```
return wrapper()
```

I am using Head First Python, but this topic I feel is not described very well in there, please suggest any video or a good resource so that I can understand it.

Comment: "please suggest any video or a good resource" => that's OT here - and well, the best resources are the official language doc and the CPython source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how functions return functions.

As already explained by LTheriault, in python everything is an object. Not only this, but also everything happens at runtime - the `def` statement is an executable statement, which creates a `function` object from the code within the `def` block and bind this object to the function's name in the current namespace - IOW it's mostly syntactic sugar for some operations you could code manually (a very welcome syntactic sugar though - building a function object "by hand" is quite a lot of work).

Note that having functions as "first-class citizens" is not Python specific - that's the basis of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

> I mean in what order does interpreter interprets this function:

```
def decorator(another_func):
    def wrapper():
        print('before actual function')
        return another_func()
    print('pos')
    return wrapper
```

Assuming the `decorator` function is declared at the module top-level: the runtime first takes the code block that follows the `def` statement, compiles it into a `code` object, creates a `function` object (instance of type 'function') from this `code` object and a couple other things (the arguments list etc), and finally binds this function object to the declared name (nb: 'binds' => "assigns to").

The inner `def` statement is actually only executed when the outer function is called, and it's executed anew each time the outer function is called - IOW, each call to `decorator` returns a new function instance.

The above explanation is of course quite simplified (hence partially inexact), but it's enough to understand the basic principle.

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding the difference is understanding that *everything* is an object in python, including functions. When you use the name of the function without parenthesis (`return wrapper`), you are returning the actual function itself. When you use parenthesis, you're calling the function. Take a look at the following example code:

```
def foo(arg):
    return 2

bar = foo
baz = foo()
qux = bar()
bar()
```

If you print baz or qux, it will print two. If you print `bar`, it will give you the memory address to reference the function, not a number. But, if you *call* the function, you are now printing the results of th